# 2's complement of a variable when variable is multiplied by some constant

Tags: number-systems

P is a 16-bit signed integer. The 22's complement representation of P is $(F87B)_{16}$. The 2's complement representation of 8×P is

One method is to use left shift to solve this. We use left shift 3 times to get the result.

Result is -

$(C3D8)_{16}$

But I am trying to solve it using one another method but not successful. So I want to know what's wrong in following method -

2's complement of P = $(F87B)_{16}$

1's complement of P = $(F87A)_{16}$

Original P = $(0785)_{16}$

Now 8P =  $(6280)_{16}$

It's 2's complement =  $(9D80)_{16}$

Wrong answer.

Comment: Which bit holds the sign ? $P=(\color{blue}{F}8\color{blue}{7}B)_{16}=(\color{blue}{1111}1000\color{blue}{0111}1011)_2$ in hexadecimal and binary respectively. You want to multiply by $(8)_{16}$ ?

Comment: Yes I want to multiply by 8.

Comment: Figure out which bit holds the sign & figure out how the number is held & then do $3$ left or right shifts and preserve the sign.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is, that you used decimal representation in $785_{10} \times 8 = 6280_{10}$ instead of hexadecimal. Correct:
$$785_{16} \times 8 = 3C28_{16}$$
 and the 2's complement is $C3D8_{16}$.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand.

Comment: I do not understand, what you do not understand. You wrote:
**Now** $8P =  (6280)_{16}.$ This is wrong. In base 16 you have $8P =  3C28_{16}!$